# Sorting a json array in a single flowfile based on a Json attribute : Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have been trying nifi and wanted to know how to sort an array of json by an attribute. 
I have Json like this

[{“name”:”Backham”,”createdDate”:”2018-05-07 06:30:09”},{“name”:”Rooney”,”createdDate”:”2016-05-12 19:50:03”},{“name”:”Ronaldo”,”createdDate”:”2019-01-07 06:30:09”}]

I have to sort by createdDate asc/desc.

I know that I can write a custom processor to sort the data and send it back. Is there any other better way of doing this? 
Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **Query record processor** in NiFi.
Configure and enable the Record Reader/Writer controller services(JsonPath Reader/JsonSetWriter).

Add new property in Query Record processor as

**OrderbyCreatedDate**

```
SELECT * from FLOWFILE Order By createdDate DESC
```

Now queryrecord processor will execute above SQL staetment on the **flowfile content** and gives output flowfile with sorted order based on createddate field.

Use the OrderbyCreatedDate relation from QueryRecord processor for further processing.

For more details regarding configuring/usage of Queryrecord processor refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html)
link.