# How to order by fetch data in NIFI QueryDataBaseTable processor

Tags: apache-nifi

How to guarantee data sequence every time when fetching delta table by NiFi QueryDataBaseTable processor. The table has an incremental field called "SEQNUM". And set up the "Maximum-value Columns" by "SEQNUM" in QueryDataBaseTable processor. Has any method to order by fetching delta table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you got the result flowfile from `QueryDatabaseTable` processor

- Then use `QueryRecord` processor add new sql query with **`order by`** clause in it.
- By using `QueryRecord` processor we are making sure the **`order of seqnum in each flowfile`** is arranged either `asc/desc`.
- if you are having more than `one flowfile` as result of `QueryDatabaseTable` then by using `MergeRecord` processor merge the flowfiles into one then connect the `merged` connection to QueryRecord processor for ordering the data in flowfile (but this is not optimal way instead of `NiFi` consider **`Hive`** for these kind of heavy lifts).

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311233/sorting-a-json-array-in-a-single-flowfile-based-on-a-json-attribute-apache-nif/50311441#50311441) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html) links for more details regards to QueryRecord processor.